# xiaomi redmi a pro external keyboard in german

Tags: android, keyboard, external

My Xiaomi Redmi 8 Pro Mobile Phone won't change from standard english keyboard layout to german layout connected to external keyboard logitec k120. Android Version 11RP1A.200720.011 and MIUI Version 12.5.7.0(RGGEUXM). Wheres the file for standard language and how to substitude letters manualy direct from phone?